# How to run two or more Docker environments with nginx and ssl enabled

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I had 2 Docker environments running on the same host, each environment has 1 container for postgres, 1 for nginx and 1 for my web app. These were accessible via our internal IP and port.

Then we've added self-signed certificates for each one as well as named servers in the nginx config. The we redeployed them. The first one (production) booted ok and it works fine. **The staging also boots, but when I visit the named url I get the production app.** My guess is this has something to do with the port mapping which eludes me still.

Here are the nginx and compose files:

1. Production

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      bash -c "bundle exec hanami db migrate
      && bundle exec rake initial_settings:add_default_language
      && bundle exec rake initial_settings:add_session_validity
      && bundle exec rake import_user:create
      && bundle exec rake super_admin:create
      && bundle exec rake create_parser_rules:start
      && bundle exec hanami server"
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres:
  nginx:
```

```
user nginx;

events {}

http {
    server {
         listen 80;
         server_name my_app.my_domain.com;
         return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
         }

    upstream appname {
        server web:2300;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        server_name my_app.my_domain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/app-nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/app-nginx-selfsigned.key;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://appname;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

Staging

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_staging:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    image: tmsr-stage:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      bash -c "bundle exec hanami db migrate
      && bundle exec rake initial_settings:add_default_language
      && bundle exec rake initial_settings:add_session_validity
      && bundle exec rake import_user:create
      && bundle exec rake super_admin:create
      && bundle exec rake create_parser_rules:start
      && bundle exec hanami server"
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_staging:
  nginx:
```

```
user nginx;

events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app-stage.my_domain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }



    upstream app-stage{
        server web:2300;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        server_name app-stage.my_domain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/stage-nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/stage-nginx-selfsigned.key;


        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://app-stage;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to only specify the ports in staging like so:

```
- 80
- 443
```

EDIT:

I've changed the staging nginx port section of the docker-compose to the above no mapping version:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - 80
        - 443
```

and after booting the containers here is the output of ports:

```
PORTS                                                                                NAMES
0.0.0.0:49230->80/tcp, :::49230->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49229->443/tcp, :::49229->443/tcp   app_staging_nginx_1
2300/tcp                                                                             app_staging_web_1
0.0.0.0:49228->5432/tcp, :::49228->5432/tcp                                          app_staging_postgres_1
0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091->80/tcp, :::8091->80/tcp         app_prod_nginx_1
2300/tcp                                                                             app_prod_web_1
0.0.0.0:49165->5432/tcp, :::49165->5432/tcp                                          app_prod_postgres_1
```

I'm guessing the random port numbers are assigned automatically since the mapping is removed for staging. Before switching to named servers and ssl the apps were running like so:
http://IP123:8091 - prod
http://IP123:8093 - stage

So the 49165 is now assigned automatically.

But visiting the staging url just renders the production app still.

END EDIT

EDIT 28. 5. 2023

I've tried removing the binding in both compose file as shown above, but the staging url still takes me to production. I've then tried the other SSL port for staging:

```
ports:
  - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
  - 8443:8443
```

I've also updated the port in the nginx conf file.

This actually shows the staging app but I need to visit the URL: `https://my_app-stage.my_domain.com:8443/`. Without specifying the 8443 port it still takes me to production.

I still have no solution, since this can't work for another 5 deployments.

END EDIT 28. 5. 2023

The problem persists. How can I then correctly setup these ports?

Best, seba

Comment: What di you mean by 2 environment on same host ?

Comment: Effectively 2 docker networks on an Ubuntu server. 1 for app in production and 1 for app in staging. Each has 3 containers: DB, nginx and app.

Comment: Are these docker compose files in 2 different folders ? Or in the same folder ?

Comment: They are completely separate: /app_prod/app/docker-compose.yml and /app_stage/app/docker-compose.yaml. Like I said, before adding the ssl ports both apps worked side by side without problem, but now, if I visit https://app_stage.my_domain.com I effectively get the production app. If I boot the staging in foreground I see there are no requests coming in.

Comment: can you check if the production container is running ?

Comment: Yes, the production is running. `docker ps -a` lists all containers as expected. I probably made a mistake when binding 443:443 in production. Then I wanted to test new features in staging and only then I noticed that I basically get production on the staging url.

Comment: I won't be able to stop the production before the weekend but even then I won't know what to start fixing. :(

Comment: replace $container_name with the name of your nginx staging container.

Comment: by running this command, if you see your production container in the output, it means that your production container is in the staging environment.

Comment: I get this error: -r: command not found.

Comment: try this one.
```docker network inspect $(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.NetworkID}}{{end}}' $container_name)```

Comment: No, I see just staging containers. Also, SO suggest moving this to chat. I haven't seen this before. Should I?

Comment: @MichealChoudhary I've got some updates if you'll have any idea how to fix this.